# Pyspark - recommendation engine - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I am trying to compile the following code with Pyspark 2.0 and Python 3.5

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

#----- DEFINE FUNCTIONS


def get_counts_and_averages(ID_and_ratings_tuple):
    nratings = len(ID_and_ratings_tuple[1])
    return ID_and_ratings_tuple[0], (nratings, float(sum(x for x in ID_and_ratings_tuple[1]))/nratings)

#-----Create Spark Context

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Recommendation Engine")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

# ---- CREATE USER ID AND RATINGS


new_user_ID = 0

# The format of each line is (userID, movieID, rating)
new_user_ratings = [
     (0,260,4), # Star Wars (1977)
     (0,1,3), # Toy Story (1995)
     (0,16,3), # Casino (1995)
     (0,25,4), # Leaving Las Vegas (1995)
     (0,32,4), # Twelve Monkeys (a.k.a. 12 Monkeys) (1995)
     (0,335,1), # Flintstones, The (1994)
     (0,379,1), # Timecop (1994)
     (0,296,3), # Pulp Fiction (1994)
     (0,858,5) , # Godfather, The (1972)
     (0,50,4) # Usual Suspects, The (1995)
    ]
new_user_ratings_RDD = sc.parallelize(new_user_ratings)
print('New user ratings: %s' % new_user_ratings_RDD.take(10))

# ----- Read in data for small ratings data file and put in formation (userID, movieID, rating)

complete_ratings_raw_data = sc.textFile("file:///sparkcourse/ml-latest-small/ratings.csv")
complete_ratings_raw_data_header = complete_ratings_raw_data.take(1)[0]

complete_ratings_data = complete_ratings_raw_data.filter(lambda line: line!=complete_ratings_raw_data_header)\
    .map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda tokens: (tokens[0],tokens[1],tokens[2])).cache()



movie_ID_with_ratings_RDD = complete_ratings_data.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[2])).groupByKey()
movie_ID_with_avg_ratings_RDD = movie_ID_with_ratings_RDD.map(get_counts_and_averages)
movie_rating_counts_RDD = movie_ID_with_avg_ratings_RDD.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0]))

print(movie_rating_counts_RDD.take(4))
```

In summary what this does is read in a bunch of data movies rating data from movielens and try to apply some simple map functions.

There is an issue with the `get_counts_and averages` function as the traceback gives the following:

org.ap

```
ache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 172, in main
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 167, in process
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1306, in takeUpToNumLeft
  File "c:/sparkcourse/test-recommendation.py", line 8, in get_counts_and_averages
    return ID_and_ratings_tuple[0], (nratings, float(sum(x for x in ID_and_ratings_tuple[1]))/nratings)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16/08/22 19:55:24 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 172, in main
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 167, in process
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1306, in takeUpToNumLeft
  File "c:/sparkcourse/test-recommendation.py", line 8, in get_counts_and_averages
    return ID_and_ratings_tuple[0], (nratings, float(sum(x for x in ID_and_ratings_tuple[1]))/nratings)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

16/08/22 19:55:24 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/sparkcourse/test-recommendation.py", line 49, in <module>

  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1310, in take
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py", line 941, in runJob
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 933, in __call__
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 172, in main
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 167, in process
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1306, in takeUpToNumLeft
  File "c:/sparkcourse/test-recommendation.py", line 8, in get_counts_and_averages
    return ID_and_ratings_tuple[0], (nratings, float(sum(x for x in ID_and_ratings_tuple[1]))/nratings)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:441)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 172, in main
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 167, in process
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "c:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1306, in takeUpToNumLeft
  File "c:/sparkcourse/test-recommendation.py", line 8, in get_counts_and_averages
    return ID_and_ratings_tuple[0], (nratings, float(sum(x for x in ID_and_ratings_tuple[1]))/nratings)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

The issue appears to be: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str', but I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on as there shouldn't be any strings or ints.

Interestingly if I print out the command: `print(movie_ID_with_avg_ratings_RDD.take(4)` it works ...

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
```

`line` is expecting to be a string, but it is a int tuple. You don't need this map.

Comment: Not sure that is right ... I still get same error. When I print out the line `complete_ratings_data` I get the format `[('1', ',', '1'), ('1', ',', '2'),  ...` if I remove the map and `[('1', '16', '4.0'), ('1', '24', '1.5'), ...` if I keep the map

Comment: in this case, the tuples you are loading through the file "ratings.csv" are str tuples (you still don't need that map), different from the tuples in "new_user_ratings". You need to  convert then to int before mapping or in the map like .map(lambda tokens: (int(tokens[0]),int(tokens[1]),int(tokens[2])))